# parallelize a nested for loop in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to parallelize the below code in R. It's a nested for loop.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my_dataset_preprocessed)){
    for (j in 1:ncol(my_dataset_preprocessed)){
      my_dataset_preprocessed[i,j] = min( my_dataset_preprocessed[i,j], 0.1 ) 
    }
}
```

I am trying the below code using doParallel

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(detectCores())
clusterExport(cl, "my_dataset")

threshold_par <- function (X) { 
  co <- foreach(i=1:nrow(X)) %:%
                foreach (j=1:ncol(X)) %dopar% {   
                  co = min( X[i,j], 0.1 )
                }
  matrix(unlist(co), ncol=ncol(X))
}

system.time(threshold_par(my_dataset))
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "invalid 'type' (list) of argument"

Is there any better way to parallelize this code (may be using parLapply)? If not, how do I fix the above code?

Comment: I think `lapply(my_dataset_preprocessed, function(x) pmin(x, 0.1))` would be simpler to do.

Comment: If your data is a matrix, this should work: `my_dataset[my_dataset > 0.1] <- 0.1`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare `cl`. The following worked if you remove `clusterExport(cl, "my_dataset")`

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)    
registerDoParallel(detectCores())
getDoParWorkers()
# [1] 8

threshold_par <- function (X) { 
  co <- foreach(i=1:nrow(X)) %:%
                foreach (j=1:ncol(X)) %dopar% {   
                  co = min( X[i,j], 0.1 )
                }
  matrix(unlist(co), ncol=ncol(X))
}

test <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
system.time(threshold_par(test))
#      user  system elapsed 
#      0.01    0.00    0.02
```

Comment: I did declare cl before, that's not the issue. even if I remove that line, it's throwing the same error

Comment: Ok. btw, I started a new R session, and it worked again without error...so not sure why there's a difference. Could you try your same code with `%do%` instead of `%dopar%`?

Comment: %do% gives me the same error. I tried your matrix and it ran properly. So, the issue is with the structure then. Below is the traceback of the error:   
 
 5 stop(simpleError(msg, call = expr)) 
 4 e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) 
 3 foreach(i = 1:nrow(X)) %:% foreach(j = 1:ncol(X)) %dopar% {
  co = min(X[i, j], 0.1)
 } 
 2 threshold_par(test) 
 1 system.time(threshold_par(test))

Comment: This is why you should try to provide data that reproduces your error. But sounds like you've pinpointed the trouble.

Comment: I have solved it. I unlisted the unlisted the matrix and built the matrix again to reset the column indexes. Now it's working fine

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out